# PHP rearrange items in an array by categories

Tags: php, arrays, organization

I have a file that looks like this, that takes data from a JSON file and outputs it:

```
<?php
$game = "Test";
$itemsArray = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://test.com/stamps.json"), true);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Image</th><th>Name</th><th>Difficulty</th><th>Description</th></tr>";

foreach ($itemsArray as $item) {
    $name = $item['name'];
    $stamps = $item['stamps'];

    if ($name == $game) {
        foreach ($stamps as $stampData) {

            $stampID = $stampData['stamp_id'];
            $stampName = $stampData['name'];
            $stampLevel = $stampData['rank_token'];
            $stampDescription = $stampData['description'];
            $stampMember = $stampData['is_member'];
            $stampID = $stampData['stamp_id'];

            if ($stampMember == "true") {
                $stampMember = "Yes";
            } else {
                $stampMember = "No";
            }

            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo "Coming soon";
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            print_r($stampName);
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            print_r(ucwords($stampLevel));
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            print_r($stampDescription.".");
            echo "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";

        }
    }
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

However, it outputs the data in the order it is in the JSON file. Which is all mixed up.

I was wondering if there was a way that I could sort the output it by the categories that $stampData['rank_token'] holds.

$stampData['rank_token'] holds the categories easy, medium, hard, and extreme. Is there a way that I can make this script output the categories in this order: easy, medium, hard, extreme?

Small example of the array after the JSON decode:

```
Array
(
[13] => Array
        (
            [name] => Blah blah
            [description] => Blah blah blah
            [parent_group_id] => 8
            [display] => Blah : Blah
            [stamps] => Array
                (
                    [73] => Array
                        (
                            [stamp_id] => 73
                            [name] => Blah
                            [is_member] => 
                            [rank] => 1
                            [description] => Blah blah blah
                            [rank_token] => easy
                        )

                    [80] => Array
                        (
                            [stamp_id] => 80
                            [name] => Blah
                            [is_member] => 
                            [rank] => 2
                            [description] => Blah blah blah
                            [rank_token] => medium
                        )

                 )
          )
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your question. If you want to sort your array structure according to your custom sort use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Answer (score 0):

See PHP's usort

```
function my_compare($a, $b) {
  if ($a["rank_token"] > $b["rank_token"]) return 1;
  if ($a["rank_token"] < $b["rank_token"]) return -1;
  return 0;
}

usort($stampData, "my_compare");
```

Comment: Thanks! However, how would I use this with the actual words? Like: easy, medium, hard, and extreme?